MockMVC test controller from other module
Given this maven modules:

web = MVC Layer (Spring MVC Project with Controllers)
client = WebClient (Spring Webflux WebClient)

How can i integration test the client module to fetch information from a running web controller of another module?
Currently i'm adding a reference of client to the web module, but i´m curious if there might be other ways?

I would test the 2 modules separately:

web: service tests + controller tests (maybe mocking the services)
client: test the client-services where the server is mocked. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mocking-webclient

Then there should be 100% test code coverage.

Consider Spring cloud contract and apply Consumer Driven Contract pattern in your tests, a general neutral step:

Define the contract(json, yml, or groove format) between the service provider(web here) and consumer(client).
Generate stubs and complete the tests on the consumer side.
Verify the stubs on the provider side.

Check the detailed tutorial from Spring Cloud Contract Reference Doc.
Check my example project(a bit old) using Spring Cloud Contract, https://github.com/hantsy/spring-microservice-sample?tab=readme-ov-file#spring-cloud-contracts.
